# Could getError() method return nothing or empty list when state is "Error"?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

In the Lightning documentation

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm

they advise us to check the result of response.getError() on null and undefined.

But, is there any possibility that response.getError() will return null, undefined or empty list when the state is equal to "Error"?

Relevant code:

```
    getSomething : function (component) {
        let action = component.get('c.getSomethingFromApex');
        action.setParams({webLeadId : component.get('v.someId')});
        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            let state = response.getState();
            if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
                let result = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
                component.set('v.someAttribute', result.endDate);
            } else if (state == 'ERROR') {
                let errors = response.getError();
                let message = 'Unknown error';
                if (Array.isArray(errors) && errors.length) {
                    message = errors[0].message;
                }
                console.error(message);
            } else {
                console.log('Unknown error');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

Apex:

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getWebLead(String someId) {
       1. Return SOQl;
       2. throw new AuraHandledException(null) => [{}];
       3. Return nothing (void) just make for instance callout;
       4. ...
    }
```

Comment: Can you add relevant code?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I have updated the question.

Comment: Sorry, can you add apex code as well?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: On top of my head, yes, if you dont throw `AuraHandledException` , lets say you let DML exception to surface. Or there is LimitException

Comment: If I do not throw aura handled expetion but I have NullPoiterException, then getError() method returns  [{"exceptionType":"System.NullPointerException","isUserDefinedException":false,"message":"Attempt to de-reference a null object","stackTrace":"Class.ClassName.getSomething: line 26, column 1"}]